# Can the cure for your disease fail?

Tags: plague-inc

On Plague INC, once the humans make a cure for your disease, is it possible for it to not work and them have to re-make it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, once the cure is complete the game is essentially over. New infections won't happen, but some will still die off.

Comment: The cure probably does fail several times during the countdown. But when it hits 100% it has been perfected.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot evolve your disease in any way to make an existing cure ineffective, as far as I know.

Although, with Necro-Virus, It is possible to still win (although very hard) after the cure reaches %100.  Instead of infecting new people, existing zombies kill off healthy people - and some of those become zombies.

Answer (score 0):

No, the disease cannot become cure-resistant. The only game mode I know of is the Immune Plague, which is an in app purchase and a cheat plague, along with Hidden and Unlimited Plague.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to make a cure fail, and this happened by extreme luck. I was playing fungus on mega brutal, still trying to beat it, and the cure had just hit 100%, and was being distributed. I had recently evolved total organ failure, and was beginning to get DNA points for killing quickly, but not enough DNA to get a genetic reshuffle. I immediately opened up the abilities and symptoms, and devolved things I didn’t need. I got exactly enough points for a genetic reshuffle. The cure went down. It had cured some people, and now I was killing way faster than I was infecting. I evolved necrosis, reinfecting everyone that had been cured, and then I won in a matter of time. The cure was at 97% when I won. So I can now say that I beat the cure, even when it was complete.